# Custom action bar button style color issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am currently developing a chat application and I'd like the chat activity header to be clickable so that I can start another activity. I've got this working with a custom ActionBar and this layout code:

```xml
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation"
android:id="@+id/actionbarTitle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:text="@string/app_name"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="20sp" />
```

However, this does not match the style of the native action bar because the ripple animation color is different from the other navigation buttons:

[image]
This is how the native button looks.

[image]
And this is how my text looks when clicked.

How can I change this to look like the native UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ripple size

Ripples on action buttons are 40dp in diameter since API 23. Add this to the `TextView`:

```
android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Remove the `style` attribute. Don't abuse styles without understanding the implications, this is clearly not a navigation button.

## Ripple color

You need to get the most intermediate context when inflating views so that theme attributes such as `?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` are resolved correctly.

**Option a)**

You can but the `TextView` directly in your `Toolbar` in the XML layout file.

**Option b)**

When adding the `TextView` manually to a toolbar use a `LayoutInflater` from said `Toolbar`.

```
val context = toolbar.context
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
```

**Option c)**

When setting this `TextView` as an `ActionBar` custom view use the Action Bar's themed context.

```
val context = supportActionBar!!.themedContext
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
```

## Text color

Replace

```
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="20sp"
```

with

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
```

for standard font size and text color inherited from theme in case you start using light Action Bar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've tried it and the ripple still does not look like the native one because it is three times as big :/. Any more ideas?

Comment: @Twometer Ripple without a set radius is drawn as a circle around the view. `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, the themed context fixed it :), Looks perfect now.